A movie where everybody act like they don't know the main character
A man wakes up in the middle of nowhere, after a party, with his college from the night before, he got back to his house by bus.
When he got back, nobody recognizes him. It was like he never existed, he lost everything.
The ending was like, he pushed his friend to a glass in a building, making them fall into the ground, but he and his friend survived and his friend explained that it's all just a prank for his birthday or something.

Sounds interesting. Can you add any more detail like year it might have been made, if it was in english, was it on TV or theaters, etc.

Just to make sure: this isn't The Game? The plot and ending you're describing sound very similar to it, but the hero there is not of college age.

The ending you describe is 100% The Game (1997) with Michael Douglass and Sean Penn.  The part about college doesn't fit into that, though.

Wealthy San Francisco financier Nicholas Van Orton gets a strange
  birthday present from wayward brother Conrad: a live-action game that
  consumes his life.

See also the Wiki for further plot description.

That's the first thing I thought of.

Me too.  Except for the college aspect. And the fact that the ending is different (I think Michael Douglas jumps off the rooftop himself, and there is no glass window).

I think when he shoots Penn, Penn falls backwards through a glass door.  It's been a while, but it's one of my favorite "twist" movies.  Unfortunately, like The usual Suspects and others, once you know the ending it's not as much fun.

Oh yeah, it is "The Game". Looks like i confuse the plot with some teen flicks, Michael Douglas sure ain't someone in that age.
and in the end, he falls into the glass rooftop, not a glass window.
Thanks for your help everyone
